# Change rendering to use only reflective scattering

Tags: rendering

I would like to generate a rendering using only reflected light from a point source, not diffuse scattering. The purpose of this is to generate an image of the object similar to the way a radar sees it. A radar can only see reflected radiation, not diffusely radiated light the way the eye can. For example:

[image]

So, for example, in this image of a missile we see the reflected energy only (the outline of the missile is shown just for clarity, the radar can only see what is light blue and green/yellow/red).

Blender should have this capability when it renders "glare" (reflected light). So basically what I need to do is generate *only* glare. Also, I need to false color the glare (as above) so that the more intense the glare, the more red the color. How can I do this in Blender?

Comment: Glare is generally achieved through post production in Blender, that means it is a "2D effect" computer over an existing image. Not sure if you are looking for something "physically accurate" but it may not be possible to achieve what you want in Blender.

Comment: You can generate only glare (as already mentioned it will be in composition nodes) by setting its Mix value up to its maximum 1 which will output edited (glared) image only. It won't provide you an image like is shown though.